# Error when using Theano in Spyder

Tags: cuda, spyder

My newly installed spyder IDE raise an error of 'nvcc compiler not found on $PATH, check your nvcc installation and try again', before I had successfully configured the theano and cuda enviroment and run the gpu test program on command console, but when I installed spyder IDE and run the same test program, it raise the error, can anyone help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you always need to start Spyder from a terminal (i.e. cmd.exe or bash) for Theano and Cuda to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution works well for me! (by the way, I'm using ubuntu, hope this works for others encountering this problem)

Comment: I'll re-add my comment as an aswer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to start Spyder from a terminal (i.e. cmd.exe or bash) for Theano and Cuda to work correctly inside it.